# MVC 3 Global.asax Redirect request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I have the SSL certificate for my `example.com` domain. I want to make a redirection if user wants to enter the site with `www.example.com`. The code below works fine, but I can't enter the site if I want to use `https://www.example.com` in the URL bar. Why ?

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
         Response.Clear();
         Response.AddHeader("Location",
                      string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, 
                                                    Request.Url.Host.Substring(4),
                                                    Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
                           );
         Response.StatusCode = 301;
         Response.End();
     }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you type `https://example.com` in the address bar of your web browser? Is the site properly loaded? If not, what error are you getting?

Comment: if I hit the `https://example.com` it is OK, but `https://www.example.com` gets me the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in Chrome (it's an example)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that there is no binding on your web server that is listening for `https://www.example.com`. You only have a valid certificate for `https://example.com`. So when you attempt to request `https://www.example.com` IIS simply drops the connection.

Comment: where can I create that binding ?

Comment: In the IIS management console, right click on the Web Site and there will be an `Edit Bindings...` popup menu where you define the bindings

Comment: OK I have already the http and https binding but the problem remains

Comment: So you have both `www.example.com` and `example.com` for both HTTP and HTTPS? I have just tested this and it worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: both HTTP and HTTPS bindings have the * in IP address and no host name

Comment: How is this even possible? You cannot have an HTTPS binding without a HOSTNAME. Make sure you have hostnames in your bindings.

Comment: if I assign the SSL certificate for the HTTPS the Host Name textbox is disabled

Comment: Yes, that's because your certificate is already bound to some host name.

Comment: And you also have a certificate for `www.example.com` configured in IIS?

Comment: no, only for `example.com`. That's why I make the redirection without `wwww`

Comment: But in order to make a redirect your application need to first be reached. If you do not have a binding in IIS for this url (`https://www.example.com`) how do you even expect your application to be hit and your code executed? Don't forget that the request first arrives at IIS and much later at your application code.

Comment: I know, but if I want to set the `HTTPS` binding I can't point the `www.example.com` in the Host Name textbox because it is disabled

Comment: It's weird that the hostname textbox is disabled when you select an HTTPS binding. Doesn't seem to be the case on my IIS. Your question seems more suitable to http://serverfault.com. You could ask on how to configure a website in IIS that will listen to both `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com`. I am not an expert in system administration and IIS configuration.